# How to mock a private class method with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, private

**Hey Folks!
I'm researching a way to mock a private class method.**

*Before I we begin I'd like to give you some context. Firstly I am not doing this on production, initially I tried to mock it (the private class method) and decided against it, partly because I realised it was just wrong to do so and partly because I couldn't figure out how to do it .
On that note some part of me felt that, somewhat ironically, the right way was a cop out . So now I am trying to satiate the need for knowledge .*

### Here it goes.

So, I am testing a controller for success (status **200**), which depends on the response of a class method in a module maintained by another party. This method in turn does some validation in a private class method contained in that same module. In an attempt to skip over this validation and get straight to the part where I return the data and in the process spare my testing server from incessant creation of Factory models...

##### I tried to:

`allow(TheOtherModule.Class).to receive(:this_private_class_method).and_return(whatever)`

To my great disappointment I found such things cannot be achieved like that, `allow_any_instance_of` was of no help either. This led to some desperate attempts like trying to:

`allow(ThisModule.Class).to receive(:send).with('this_private_class_method').and_return(whatever)`

...as well as some more elaborate ones like putting a converter of methods in `before` and `after` like so:

```rb
saved_private_methods = ThisModule.Class.private_methods 
before :each do
    ThisModule.Class.class_eval { public *saved_private_methods }
end
after :each do
    ThisModule.Class.class_eval { private *saved_private_methods }
end
```

which just failed spectacularly because I copied it and class_eval, somewhat counterintuitively doesn't target class methods, the result of which is that the methods would be found by `private_methods`...uhm...method but once the conversion was attempted they would not be evaluated, so instead you have to use...

```rb
# Oh and dropped this it's overkill
# saved_private_methods = ThisModule.Class.private_methods
before :each do
    ThisModule.Class.instance_eval { public :this_private_class_method }
end
after :each do
    ThisModule.Class.instance_eval { private :this_private_class_method }
end
```

...which worked beautifully at what it was supposed to do except that rspec `allow` still wouldn't pick it up...

**So now I am turning to the Bastion of knowledge that is SO in hopes of finding a way it could be done or at least a definite answer of why it cannot.**

Comment: Not sure I understand can you provide a verifiable example you are having an issue with because `allow` syntax can mock private an public methods alike [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/mockprivate#spec.rb) with a little setup

Comment: In the meantime I tried a few more things that weirded me out... i'll add that to the examples also

Comment: Did you look at my example? I order to assist in your particular instance we would need to know specifically what you are trying to mock/stub. Implementation is very important in this case.

Comment: Yeah I looked at it, it doesn't really match my side, i'm gonna fork it and add it here 

Comment: Okay I created my test on the fork of your replit and it passes, only I don't understand, either what you did in the main.rb or what's wrong in my env
https://replit.com/@srbiotik/mockprivate#spec.rb... The only difference is that I am testing a request type which may or may not play a role?

Comment: main.rb is just a bunch of setup so that Rspec works on "replit", most of this would generally be contained in "spec_helper.rb". I cannot help with what is wrong in your environment since I do not have access to that and you have not provided any context in this question.

Comment: I'll try to add some more detail...

Comment: @engineersmnky What kind of context do you need?

Comment: What are you trying to mock that isn't working?

Comment: have you tried passing class name `TheOtherModule::#{CLASS_NAME}` instead on `TheOtherModule.Class` and `ThisModule.Class`. I think `TheOtherModule.Class` and `ThisModule.Class` returns `Module` not the class which you are expecting.

Comment: I've got to say I haven't. I'll try it today